# SIlverlight and SharePoint

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm currently trying to get data Asynchronously in silverlight to enable me to populate some auto complete boxes and some other display controls.

My silverlight app is based at the root of the site.

With the client object model it's easy to get the title of every web and subweb and sub webs (recusive) however in silverlight i'm not to sure how i go about this.

I have the webs(subWeb1 collection) of the root web and i believe( broken this recently :() i can get the webs(Sub Web 2 collection) but i can't seem to gain access to a list in subWeb 2 that i need access to! I keep getting

The collection has not been initialised. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested

Could anyone shed any light on how you would do this?

Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

There is a Silverlight Client Object Model for just this thing. [Here](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/255776.aspx/1) is a post that explains exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: This explains how to get a list item which i can do if i am getting it from the site that my web part is in. I could do this what i am struggling with i believe after going through the below video is passing the correct objects in to the context.load as i iterate through the webs